# Presenting logistic model fit graphically 

Tags: data-visualization, logistic

I have run 3 separate logistic regressions and would somehow like to summarize how well the model fits the data graphically.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not a complete answer, but this [blog post](http://statisticsforum.wordpress.com/2011/07/26/statistical-numerology/) over on the Statistics Forum by Michael Lavine may be a good start for some ideas. It is mainly aimed at identifying outliers, so not a complete picture of model fit I suppose.

Comment: What do you mean by "fits"?  And what do you mean by "data"?  As the logistic model estimates probabilities and the observed Y=0 or 1, these are not easy questions.

Comment: @Frank Harrel I'm trying to see how well a model predicts the observed values which are both binary. I was just trying to ask how I could graphically present the different AIC's or other measures obtained

Comment: "Well" is hard to define here.  I'd suggest fitting a model that has the right number of parameters for the effective sample size (allowing multiple terms for apriori strong variables not known to act linearly), putting in subject-matter-driven interaction terms, then plotting predicted values from that model.  Partial effect plots are very helpful.  The R rms package makes this easy.  See http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/RmS/rms.pdf

Comment: Why not a simple bar graph that shows the proportion which it succeeds at predicting or fails at predicting, and the proportion of times it gives a false positive / false negative? I think that's something even a layman would understand equally well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First I want to reiterate what others have said in the comments: this is in general a difficult problem with no easy solution.

With that in mind, *one* way of assessing model fit with logistic regression models when your *primary interest* is simply predictive power is to plot ROCs. Here's an example (with caveats) using the `pROC` package in R:

```
library(pROC)

#Fit three logistic models
m1 <- glm(case ~ age,data=infert,family=binomial())
m2 <- glm(case ~ age + parity + education + induced,
          data=infert,family=binomial())
m3 <- glm(case ~ age+parity+education+spontaneous+induced,
          data=infert,family=binomial())

#Plot the three ROCs, adding the AUC for each
plot.roc(infert$case,fitted(m1),print.auc = TRUE)
plot.roc(infert$case,fitted(m2),add=TRUE,col = "blue",
         print.auc=TRUE,print.auc.y = 0.45)
plot.roc(infert$case,fitted(m3),add = TRUE,col = "red",
         print.auc = TRUE,print.auc.y = 0.4)
```

[image]

The basic idea is that more area under the curve indicates a "better" model, from the perspective of prediction only.

Note that my example is meant only to illustrate how to make such a graph, as I've plotted these curves using the *in-sample* fitted values, rather than those obtained using cross validation, bootstrapping or a hold-out test set, which in general is preferable.

I'll end by repeating my warning that this is far from *the* way to assess model fit. It is just *a* way that is limited to assessing predictive accuracy.

Comment: what do you mean by the more are under the curve? how is the curve defined?

Comment: @Daniel - See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) for a basic discussion of ROC curves. In my example, the red curve has more area under it, so it that would indicate a "better" fit.

Comment: so basically the highr the value of AUC the better the model?

Comment: @Daniel - Yes, but please mind all my caveats if you actually use this! There are no shortcuts to assessing model fit!

Comment: ROC curves have little to do with model fit.

Comment: @FrankHarrell That's why I included loads of caveats, and addressed this answer toward the OP's specific request for a way to assess how well the model predicts the response.

Comment: This gets back to the big question of what "well" means, and the important consideration of calibration vs. discrimination.  Thanks -

Comment: @Frank Harrell so basically in a nutshell, in plain words how would you summarize 'what is required to properly assess model fit?'

Comment: @Daniel - His point, I think, is that this question can't really be answered in a "nutshell". Whole books have been written on this topic. And logistic regression models are a particularly difficult case, at that. I provided an illustration of how to evaluate predictive accuracy, since you mentioned that in particular, but that is only one _potential_ facet of what a statistician would call "model fit".

Comment: Some recommendations for assessment of model fit.  (1) Make the model fit up-front as much as possible so you don't need to worry so much (e.g., don't assume anything is linear; use regression splines); (2) If you have some hope that the model is simple, add more complex terms to the model and assess their added value (e.g., partial chi-square chunk test); (3) Draw a bootstrap overfitting-corrected smooth calibration curve; (4) Summarize predictive discrimination (show histogram of predicted risks or compute $R^2$ measure or Somers' $D_{xy}$ rank correlation (related to $c$-index or ROC area).

Answer (score 2):

A good reference for the kind of graphs you seem to want is John Fox, "Effect Displays for Multinomial and Proportional-Odds Logit Models," in Sociological Methodology (2006). See the citations to his earlier work. He implements these techniques in R and S-Plus in his book that accompanies his text on linear regression.